# Java android animate hide and unhide view and resize button

Tags: java, android

I try to animate this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/theView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#111111"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Click to Toggle"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

When I clicked first time button I want to animate two actions:
 animate show View and animate resize a button

And when I clicked second time I want to: animate GONE View and resize a button.

I do this but it does not work good:

```
View viewToAnimate;
Button button;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);

    viewToAnimate = findViewById(R.id.theView);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(viewToAnimate.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        Animation out = AnimationUtils.makeOutAnimation(this, false);
        viewToAnimate.startAnimation(out);
        Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_out);
        button.startAnimation(in);
        viewToAnimate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_in);
        Animation out = AnimationUtils.makeOutAnimation(this, true);
        button.startAnimation(out);
        viewToAnimate.startAnimation(in);
        viewToAnimate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not call `setVisibility(View.GONE)` until the animation finishes. So you have to listen for the animation and change visibility when animation ends.

Updated code:

```
View viewToAnimate;
Button button;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);

    viewToAnimate = findViewById(R.id.theView);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(viewToAnimate.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        Animation out = AnimationUtils.makeOutAnimation(this, false);
        viewToAnimate.startAnimation(out);
        Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_out);
        button.startAnimation(in);
        out.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                viewToAnimate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
    } else {
        Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_in);
        Animation out = AnimationUtils.makeOutAnimation(this, true);
        button.startAnimation(out);
        viewToAnimate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewToAnimate.startAnimation(in);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marcos CG  but I have one more question it is a possible to do on fist cliked slide from out to down view and animate a button ? and on next clicked slide down to up view and resize a buttons ?

Comment: Please as it is a different question, consider creating it as a new one :) If I have solve the first question, please upvote the answer :D